# In Javascript, when I separate the strings, how should I run the method for each string after the split?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

```
function processPathLettersIntoArray(source){
    source = source.split("M").join(";M");
    source = source.split("L").join(";L");
    source = source.split("z").join(";z");
    source = source.split(";");
    source = source.slice(1);
    return source.map(mapGroup);
}
```

This is my split method.

```
function gcodeXY(source){
   var [xVal, yVal] = source.split(",");
   return `X${xVal} Y${yVal}`
}
let start="X0 Y0"; //another side effect :-(

function mapGroup(grp){
    let s=grp.split(" ");
    if (s[0]=="M"){
        start=gcodeXY(s[1]);
        last=s[1];
        return "G0 F200 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="L"){
        start=gcodeXY(s[1]);
        last=s[1];
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="z"){
        last=s[1];
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    return grp;
}
```

This is how I want each string to be achieved after splitting.

```
function path2gcode(source){
    source = processPathLettersIntoArray(source);
    return source;
}
```

This is the method I need to run.
What I want ask is that in Javascript, when I separate the strings, how should I run the method for each string after the split?The picture shows the input and output examples and my current output.[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you paste the test input as text?

Comment: "M 1,2 L 2,2 L 3,3 z"

Comment: Based on what you're doing, looks like you just call `processPathLettersIntoArray` directly, so what you got is correct. You're not making use of `mapGroup` anywhere. What's your question? How to use that `mapGroup` function for array and return value?

Comment: A simple `for` loop should do the job, check my answer below

Comment: In fact, I am restricted from using for, while and goto loops, but I can use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
function processPathLettersIntoArray(source) {
  const result = source.replace(/M/g, ";M").replace(/L/g, ";L").replace(/z/g, ";z").split(';').slice(1);
  return result.map(mapGroup);
}

function gcodeXY(source) {
   const [xVal, yVal] = source.split(",");
   return `X${xVal} Y${yVal}`;
}
let start="X0 Y0"; //another side effect :-(

function mapGroup(grp) {
    let s = grp.split(" ");
    if (s[0]=="M"){
        start = gcodeXY(s[1]);
        last=s[1];
        return "G0 F200 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="L"){
        start=gcodeXY(s[1]);
        last=s[1];
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="z"){
        last=s[1];
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    return grp;
}

function path2gcode() {
  const source = 'M 1,2 L 2,2 L 3,3 z';
  return processPathLettersIntoArray(source);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
function processPathLettersIntoArray(source){
    source = source.split("M").join(";M");
    source = source.split("L").join(";L");
    source = source.split("z").join(";z");
    source = source.split(";");
    source = source.slice(1);
    output = [];
    for(i=0;i<source.length;i++) {
      output.push(mapGroup(source[i]));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Alternately, `.map` can be used

```
 function processPathLettersIntoArray(source){
        source = source.split("M").join(";M");
        source = source.split("L").join(";L");
        source = source.split("z").join(";z");
        source = source.split(";");
        source = source.slice(1);
        return source.map(mapGroup);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer！But in fact, I am restricted from using for, while and goto loops, but I can use recursion.

Comment: @Simon Added a simpler solution using `.map`

Comment: I tried it, but there are some problems.I placed a new picture to show the error, you can take a look.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Maybe a `var last = ""` at the top of the function is required?

Comment: That‘s whork! Thanks!